# custom error handling system efficiency

Tags: php, error-handling, mysqli

I have had a few nerve racking days trying to get a good error handling system in place within my site.

My error handling system is only focusing on unexpected errors e.g. mysqli errors

My site runs many mysqli queries meaning there is potential for errors to occur.

There is 3 parts to my system, and every one I am unsure on its place in best practices as well as efficiency.

**Step 1** : *catching the error*

```
$query = "
SELECT * FROM `users_account_activations` WHERE `user_ip` =?
";
$statement = $databaseHandler->mysqli->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param('s', $userIp);
$statement->execute();
$statement->store_result();
//record error, if any
$databaseHandler->mysqli->error ? error = true : error = false;
```

- Is this a good way of catching the presents of an error somewhere in a prepared statement?
- Will looking for errors at the end of the query not catch a error say in the prepare stage? or when the prepare stage fails all other fails (like falling dominoes)

**Step 2** : *recording the error*

```
error_log("Could not process query...", 3, 'log/default.log');
```

- Is this a suitible way of recording a error? as aposed to the systems that opens a file steam?

**Step 3** : *handling the after math*

Now that there is a error I need to decide on how to move forward, my system intails exiting the script and going to a standard error page saying "opps! something went wrong".

```
header('location: errorpage.php'); exit();
```

- is changing the header a good way of doing this? I am aware of the limitation of header regarding when you can use it.

Is there a better way for handing errors, this system is intended for unexpected errors. Expected errors are took care of and displayed to the users a different way.

Comment: Do you really need such a variable name like $databaseHandlingHandlerUsedToHandleADatabase? Can't you use just $db or $mysqli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right with your doubts - all the three steps are wrong.

- First, for some very strange reason **you are not recording the error message itself**. How it is supposed to fix the error without error message? What's the use of logging something like "Could not process query..."?
- Next, you have to check the result of every operation - so, prepare have to be checked too.
- Next, it will be hard to spot the error without knowing where it happened. Some debug backtrace have to be included in the error message.
- Next, there shouldn't be a Location header but just Status:500. So, instead of redirecting to error page, just include it.
- Finally, all the aforementioned tasks have to be performed in a single place, namely - in the function registered as a [custom error handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

So, the scenario have to be like this

in your bootstrap file create a code like this

```
set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    error_log("$errstr in $errfile:$errline");
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error', TRUE, 500);
    readfile("500.html");
    exit;
}
```

then, make your mysqli code like this

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("qwefq") or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
```

and have all your errors logged

Comment: Thank you, when you call the function error log, where does this place the error, does it place it in the default error log file? can you create your own destination? And what about an ajax request, how do you call a error 500, it would just call that within the request not the page, would you just look for errors from the ajax request and display an error message from there?

Comment: error log destination is set by ini directive `error_log`. if not set, goes into web-server's error log. Check your AJAX library documentation - every AJAX performing function has a variable for the HTTP status. You may check it in your JS and accordingly. See statusCode for jquery for example

Comment: Okay thanks, helped a lot, could I ask what is a php bootstrap file, is it just a file you require on every page, is it possible to require it automatically say with .htaccess or do I have to manually require it?

Comment: yes it's a file you require on every page. There is a way to do it via php.ini/.htaccess but I would advise against it